# Get views exposed filter values

Tags: views

I have a view in which I want to have a link that passes the current exposed filters values through to another custom page (not a view).

For example if the "Day One" checkbox is checked I want my link to be able to reflect this checkboxes value.

```
<a href="page?checked=day+one">Link</a>
```

Is there some form of array where all exposed values are stored when a view is shown? I can't seem to find one

Comment: exposed filters are set as variables in the url, eg, something along the lines of `www.example.com/view-url?filter=value` and thus are available to you in `$_GET`

Comment: Should have added that the view is Ajax so this is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what I needed after reading a couple of views docs.

```
 $view = views_get_current_view();
 $view->exposed_input['filter_name']
```